# kafka commands are not running from kubernetes pod hosted on AWS EKS

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, amazon-eks

I want to run kafka commands from kubernetes pod which is hosted on AWS EKS.

What would be the jaas config to EXPORT in pod local session and client.properties entry and what would be Kafka bootstrap endpoint to connect.

Below is my kafka.properties file from pod:

```
advertised.listeners=EXTERNAL://abc.com:9092,INGRESSMTLSAWS://xyz.com:9092,INGRESSMTLSONPREM://def.com:9092,INGRESSOAUTHAWS://ghi.com:9092,INGRESSOAUTHONPREM://jkl.com:9092,INTERNAL://kafka-0.svc.cluster.local:9071,MTLSONPREM://mno.com:9094,OAUTHAWS://pqr.com:9093,OAUTHONPREM://uvw.com:9095,REPLICATION://kafka-0.svc.cluster.local:9072,TOKEN://kafka-0.svc.cluster.local:9073
broker.id=XX
broker.rack=XX
confluent.metadata.server.advertised.listeners=https://internal-service-url-kafka:8090
authorizer.class.name=io.confluent.kafka.security.authorizer.ConfluentServerAuthorizer
```